# Как скрыть ненужные строки после поиска в datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, search, filter

У меня выполняется вот такой поиск по строке:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
            {
               dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                break;
            }
}
```

Я не могу использовать фильтр, т.к. у меня нет datatable. Я уже умучилась с ним (у меня `List<>` который с `AddRange` выводится, но это другая история).

Я использую две строки:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
```

Внутри последнего if-a и с их помощью скрываются те строки, в которых есть совпадение по textbox. А мне надо так, что бы скрывались те, где нет совпадений.

Пробовала ставить

```
if (!dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
```

но тогда скрывается все. Хочу как то на костылях выйти из этой ситуации.

Есть такая строка для фильтра:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
    String.Format("title like '{0}%'", textBox2.Text);
```

но выдает ошибку:

> System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта".

`(... as System.Data.DataTable)` вернул null, при попытке преобразовать `List<Films> films` в `DataTable`, говорит что это невозможно.

Comment: я провела эксперимент с else. у меня несколько столбцов: название, описание, возраст и прочее. и вот срабатывает только на названии. например я ввожу "Побег" и он оставляет строку "побег из шоушенка", но если введу "16" пропадет все

Comment: и дело не в цифрах и строках. тк часть описание тоже не ищется

Comment: Не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментариях. Вы можете отредактировать сам пост.

Comment: Проблема решена? Дайте отклик.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, имеется коллекция `List<Film> films`. И она привязана к датагриду:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = films;
```

Тогда отфильтровать данные проще всего так:

```
var filtered = films
    .Where(x => x.Title.Contains(textBox2.Text))
    .ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = filtered;
```